# Universal algorithm for generating properities

Tags: algorithm, hash, checksum

I need to make algorithm, what take random unique string (hash, whatever) and generate multiple random properities from prepaired lists.

Example: [cat algorithm]

```
color: white,black,brown
eye-color: blue, green, brown
size: 10,20,30

function algorithm(random_unique_hash){
   ...magic...
   return [color, eye-color, size]
}
```

Returned cat is absolutely unique to her string.
String is unique in whole list of strings.
Every cat must be different.
I need to be able to make hash again from properities.

Is this possible? Or it needs to work in different way? Did I need to make cat and then make unique checksum?

Where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got three colors, three eye-colors, and three sizes. That means there are exactly 3*3*3=27 different cats you can make. So the `random_unique_hash` should just be a number from 0 to 26.

To get the properties from the hash, break the hash down into indexes using division and the modulo operator, e.g.

```
index1 = random_unique_hash % 3
index2 = (random_unique_hash / 3) % 3
index3 = random_unique_hash / 9
```

The indexes can then be used to access the correct entry in each property list.

To get the hash from the properties you'll need to find the index of the property. Then combine all of the indexes to recreate the hash, like this

```
random_unique_hash = index3 * 9 + index2 * 3 + index1
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not searching this specific type. I am searching for a way where I will have milions of possible combinations from many lists with many and many options. This was just example.

Comment: @EmaMaMasoEmaSeMa Yes, but I was hoping that you would be able to understand this example well enough that you would be able to extend the concept to more lists with more options. A single 32-bit hash allows for billions of possible combinations. You break the hash down into indexes with division and modulo operations. You reassemble the hash from the indexes using multiplication.

Comment: I understand, but I need to achieve something like www.cryptokitties.co using for their cats generation. Is your example a good way to make system like this?

Comment: The system works as long as the properties are orthogonal. For example, as long as every eye-color can be used with every body color, then it works. If there are interactions between properties, like blue eyes don't work with a brown body, then things get complicated.